# manage multiple windows in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

My wxpython project requires a number of windows that can call each other with user widgets. 
I see how to create multiple panels in one Frame, but that leads to one enormous file as some panels need complex handlers.
I see how to launch several windows simultaneously, but not how to write code to move between them.
I am a python noob, but have two decades of microcontrollers and C.
Pointers would be appreciated (
pun intentional). Graham.

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to communicate between classes or frames in wxPython is to use pubsub. This allows you to send data between windows easily and call methods in other windows.

Here's a simple example:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub 


class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Secondary Frame")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        msg = "Enter a Message to send to the main frame"
        instructions = wx.StaticText(panel, label=msg)
        self.msgTxt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="")
        closeBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Send and Close")
        closeBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSendAndClose)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        flags = wx.ALL|wx.CENTER
        sizer.Add(instructions, 0, flags, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.msgTxt, 0, flags, 5)
        sizer.Add(closeBtn, 0, flags, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onSendAndClose(self, event):
        """
        Send a message and close frame
        """
        msg = self.msgTxt.GetValue()
        pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message=msg)
        pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message="test2", arg2="2nd argument!")
        self.Close()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        pub.subscribe(self.myListener, "panelListener")

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Open Frame")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFrame)

    def myListener(self, message, arg2=None):
        """
        Listener function
        """
        print("Received the following message: " + message)
        if arg2:
            print("Received another arguments: " + str(arg2))

    def onOpenFrame(self, event):
        """
        Opens secondary frame
        """
        frame = OtherFrame()
        frame.Show()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""


    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="New PubSub API Tutorial")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can read more about it at the following:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.pubsub.html
- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/
- https://github.com/schollii/pypubsub

Answer (score 1):

wx.lib.pubsub is now deprecated in wxPython. You will need to install [PyPubSub](https://pypi.org/project/PyPubSub/) now. The PyPubSub package is actually what wx.lib.pubsub was based on, so the implementation will be almost the same. You can read its documentation here.

To install PyPubSub, use [pip](https://pypi.org/project/PyPubSub/):

pip install PyPubSub
Then replace from wx.lib.pubsub import pub with from pubsub import pub.

More Details:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2019/03/28/wxpython-4-and-pubsub/

or you can use [PyDispatcher](https://pypi.org/project/PyDispatcher/)

More Details:
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/06/wxpython-using-pydispatcher-instead-of-pubsub/